# Accessing attributes in objects Scala

Tags: json, scala, jackson, json4s

An example of the sort of objects I need to grab from my json can be found in the following example(src):

```
{
  "test": {
    "attra": "2017-10-12T11:17:52.971Z",
    "attrb": "2017-10-12T11:20:58.374Z"
  },
  "dummyCheck": false,
  "type": "object",
  "ruleOne": {
    "default": 2557
  },
  "ruleTwo": {
    "default": 2557
  }
}
```

From the example above I want to access the default value under "ruleOne".
I've tried messing about with several different things below but I seem to be struggling. I can grab values like "dummyCheck" ok. What's the best way to key into where I need to go?
Example of how I am trying to get the value below:

```
import org.json4s._
import org.json4s.native.JsonMethods._
import org.json4s.DefaultFormats

implicit val formats = DefaultFormats
val test = parse(src)
println((test \ "ruleOne.default").extract[Integer])
```

Edit:
To further extend what is above:

```
  def extractData(data: java.io.File) = {
    val json = parse(data)
    val result = (json \ "ruleOne" \ "default").extract[Int]
    result
  }
```

If I was to extend the above into a function that is called by passing in:

```
extractData(src)
```

That would only ever give me RuleOne.default.. is there a way I could extend it so that I could dynamically pass it multiple string arguments to parse (like a splat)

```
  def extractData(data: java.io.File, path: String*) = {
    val json = parse(data)
    val result = (json \ path: _*).extract[Int]
    result
  }
```

so consuming it would be like

```
extractData(src, "ruleOne", "default")
```

Comment: `(test \ "ruleOne" \ "default").extract[Int]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This here works with `"json4s-jackson" % "3.6.0-M2"`, but it should work in exactly the same way with `native` backend.

```
val src = """
  |{
  |  "test": {
  |    "attra": "2017-10-12T11:17:52.971Z",
  |    "attrb": "2017-10-12T11:20:58.374Z"
  |  },
  |  "dummyCheck": false,
  |  "type": "object",
  |  "ruleOne": {
  |    "default": 2557
  |  },
  |  "ruleTwo": {
  |    "default": 2557
  |  }
  |}""".stripMargin

import org.json4s._
import org.json4s.jackson.JsonMethods._
import org.json4s.DefaultFormats

implicit val formats = DefaultFormats
val test = parse(src)
println((test \ "ruleOne" \ "default").extract[Int])
```

Output:

```
2557
```

To make it work with `native`, simply replace

```
import org.json4s.jackson.JsonMethods._
```

by

```
import org.json4s.native.JsonMethods._
```

and make sure that you have the right dependencies.

---

**EDIT**

Here is a `vararg` method that transforms string parameters into a path:

```
def extract(json: JValue, path: String*): Int = {
  path.foldLeft(json)(_ \ _).extract[Int]
}
```

With this, you can now do:

```
println(extract(test, "ruleOne", "default"))
println(extract(test, "ruleTwo", "default"))
```

Note that it accepts a `JValue`, not a `File`, because the version with `File` would be unnecessarily painful to test, whereas `JValue`-version can be tested with parsed string constants.

Comment: is there anyone I could use a splat operator to dynamically chain my root to the data?

Comment: I have expanded on the original question with an edit that hopefully explains it better

Comment: @Curious_Bop Take a look at this [`foldLeft`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49191750/get-xpath-from-command-line-in-scala/49195416#49195416) solution for a very similar question for XML. I'll try to update my answer to do the same in JSON.