# getting the value of a key in a map in Scala

Tags: json, scala, dictionary, key

I am new to scala and still needs to learn a lot. but for the time being I have this json object :

```
driverCarJSON = """{
    "collection": {
        "listing": [ 
        ],
        "cars": ["bmw", "ford", "vw"]
        ,
        "carDriverMap" :[{"car1":"driver1"},
        {"car2":"driver2"},
        {"car3":"driver3"},
        {"car4":"driver4"},
        {"car5":"driver5"}]
    }
}"""
```

I am trying to access the value of the keys in carDriverMap.
So if I want the value of "car2" it should return "driver2"

Now, I am parsing this json using this:

```
scala.util.parsing.json.JSON.parseFull(driverCarJSON)
```

This returns

```
Some(Map(collection -> Map(listing -> List(), cars -> List(bmw, ford, vw), carDriverMap -> List(Map(car1 -> driver1), Map(car2 -> driver2), Map(car3 -> driver3), Map(car4 -> driver4), Map(car5 -> driver5)))))
```

I am stuck here what should i do?

I have seen this solution using  a function

```
def getValue(parsedJson : Option[Any] , key:String): String ={
  parsedJson match {
    case Some(m : Map[String,Any]) => m(key) match {
      case d:String => d
    }
  }
}
```

and then calling it `getValue(driverCarJSON , carDriverMap["collection"][2]["car2"])`
but when i print it nothing gets printed.

Thanks

Comment: What scala version is this even? Hasn't this package been deprecated in `2.11`? Did you try using `json4s` instead? I don't remember anything at all about `json4s`, this is an indication that it didn't cause any trouble whatsoever.

Comment: hmm why would the version matter that much? the issue is how do i access that key

Comment: Of course, `getValue(driverCarJSON , "car2")` doesn't work. There is no key `"car2"` in your JSON, there is only a key `"collection"`. This has nothing to do with the "complexities of Scala". If you tried `driverCarJSON["car2"]` in any other language, it wouldn't work as well.

Comment: you re right, my mistake copying over - do you have any constructive criticism?

Comment: Also, `driverCarJSON["collection"]["carDriverMap"]["car5"]` will not work either, because despite the misleading name, `carDriverMap` is not a map but a sequence. It looks like the problems have nothing to do with Scala and more with the fact that you don't understand the structure of the JSON.

Comment: The version matters enough because `scala.util.parsing.json` has been deprecated so long ago that this package got completely purged from the newer Scala versions. I'd usually just copy the code and try it out, but I won't install 2.11 version just for that...

Comment: @JörgWMittag ok i mean my point here is how do you access that value, driverCarJSON["collection"]["carDriverMap"]["car5"] was just to illustrate my point there should be an easy way to do so. If you want to spend your day going over minute details do so.

Comment: You were asking why nothing gets printed, and further making the assumption that because nothing gets printed, there is something wrong with the code. However, you cannot make that inference, because the key you are accessing *doesn't exist*, so there *is nothing to print*.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin the scala version is 2.12

Comment: You claim that when you call `getValue(driverCarJSON , carDriverMap[""collection"][2]["car2"])` nothing gets printed. However, there is a very obvious syntax error and an equally obvious semantic error in that code, so it will not even compile. Obviously, if your Scala syntax is illegal, then the code will not parse, and if it doesn't parse, then it will not compile, and if it doesn't compile, then it will not run, and if it will not run, then it will not print anything. But again, this has nothing to do with Scala, this is true of *any* language.

Comment: @JörgWMittag I think you re more interested in showing off you great logic than helping here. Like I said scala is totally new to me, and I am not even sure what the syntax is to pass it into the getValue function

Comment: @JörgWMittag please pick a new question to work on

Comment: @JörgWMittag if you wanted to help you would have corrected the syntax error. All else is pointless. The way you call keys in scala is totally different than how you would do it in Javascript or Python for instance. So take a chill pill go about your sunday and forget this post.

Comment: The problem is that the code you are showing cannot possibly give the results you are describing. I tested that in two ways: by reading the code and executing it with pen and paper, and by downloading and installing the same version of Scala you are using and copy&pasting the code from your question. In both cases, I get a *different* result (compile error, doesn't run) from what you are describing (runs but doesn't print anything). The only explanation there is, why you are seeing different behavior is that there must be something else in your environment that is somehow strange. Maybe the …

Comment: … code you are running is not the one you think you are running. Maybe the compiler you are using is not the one you think you are using. Maybe there is something broken in your Scala installation. Without knowing what these extra factors are, it is next to impossible to diagnose the problem. I have seen questions on [so] similar to yours, where in the end it turned out that the asker was posting code from one file but was actually executing code from a file with the same name in a different directory. That would perfectly explain why the code and the behavior don't match.

Comment: @JörgWMittag ok thanks. will check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This here works with 2.11 and separate parser-combinators dependency:

```
val driverCarJSON = """{
    "collection": {
        "listing": [ 
        ],
        "cars": ["bmw", "ford", "vw"]
        ,
        "carDriverMap" :[{"car1":"driver1"},
        {"car2":"driver2"},
        {"car3":"driver3"},
        {"car4":"driver4"},
        {"car5":"driver5"}]
    }
}"""

val parsedJson = scala.util.parsing.json.JSON.parseFull(driverCarJSON).get
val d2 = parsedJson
  .asInstanceOf[Map[String, Any]]
  .apply("collection")
  .asInstanceOf[Map[String, Any]]
  .apply("carDriverMap")
  .asInstanceOf[List[Map[String, String]]]
  .apply(1)("car2")

println(d2) // output: driver2
```

But I personally find the API not terribly well thought out. I couldn't find any way to avoid all the ugly and unnecessary `asInstanceOf`s. This has been deprecated very long ago, so please consider using something newer like `json4s`, it does not suffer from the repetitive `asInstanceOf`s.

Comment: thank you. Let me try this. I didnt even know this was deprecated, this is how new I am to this scala thing. I can definitely use json4s, do you mind showing how you would use it for that purpose here?. You're right this API looks pretty convoluted..I ll accept your post as the answer though.

Comment: You might want to take a look at a [similar example with json4s](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49659726/accessing-attributes-in-objects-scala/49660627#49660627). In your concrete case, it should be something like `((parsedJson \ "collection" \ "carDriverMap")(1)) \ "car2").extract[String]`, but there are other flavors of syntax, check out [this Json4s page](http://json4s.org/) for more examples.

Comment: actually i get this error when running your code in the accepted answer:
`java.lang.ClassCastException: scala.Some cannot be cast to scala.collection.immutable.Map`    - any idea?

Comment: @uniXVanXcel If you get this exception, then you aren't running the code from the answer. You are probably running only the last part starting with `val d2 = ...`, but you have forgot the `get` in the previous line. If you don't wont to `get`, you must do pattern matching on `Some/None`.